# Building OpenSSL from source

Tags: openssl, resources

I am trying to compile OpenSSL from source.

First, I downloaded the latest version of the OpenSSL source. Then I downloaded the latest version of Perl. I registered it in environment variables. After that I tried to build OpenSSL.

I ran the developer command line as administrator and ran:

1. Tried to configure :

   ```
   perl Configure VC-WIN64 no-asm --prefix=C:\OpenSSL-Win64
   ```
2. Tried to install:

   ```
   nmake -f ms\nt.mak
   ```

   but I receive an error message:

   > Fatal error u1052.

What did I wrong and how would I assemble OpenSSL correctly?

Comment: I reformatted this question, its list-formatting, and its spelling. I also reformulated the final question.